# What is the prototype in this class?

Tags: javascript, python

In the following class:

```js
class Range2 {
    constructor(from, to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    toString() {
        console.log("Hello!");
        return `(${this.from}...${this.to})`
    }
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        for (let x = this.from; x <= this.to; x++) yield x;
    }
    includes(x) {
        return x >= this.from && x <= this.to
    }
}
r = new Range2(1, 5);
console.log(r.toString());
console.log(r.includes(3), r.includes(7));
```

What is the prototype of this `Range2` class? I know the constructor allow building object. I'm familiar with Python and so it's the same as the `__init__` :

```py
class Range2:
    def __init__(self, from, to):
        self.from = from
        self.to = to
```

But what is the prototype, and the closest equivalent in Python if there is one?

Comment: what method? You have a `Range2` class, with a `constructor` function right there, so if you construct a new instance, using the `new` keyword, that's what gets called.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans sorry I updated it. I mean what's the prototype of the `Range2` class and if there's an equivalent in python (if you know)

Comment: Since it sounds like you're asking about what some Python code would look like, I've added the tag

Comment: I still don't understand your question, `class` syntax _is_ the prototype. It's syntactic sugar for declaring a prototype to be auto-assigned during instance allocation, making things nicer to work with compared to the ancient "instantiate a function and then magically tack an object to act as prototype onto that" pattern. Type `console.log({ r })` in your dev tools and start unfolding it to see what gets constructed.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans so when creating a `new Range2(1,5)` does it first call the constructor, or assign the `Range2.prototype` first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the class syntax is functionally the same as:

```js
function Range(from, to){
  this.from = from;
  this.to = to;
}

Range.prototype = {
  toString(){
    console.log("Hello!");
    return `(${this.from}...${this.to})`;
  },
  *[Symbol.iterator](){
    for (let x = this.from; x<=this.to; x++) yield x;
  },
  includes(x){
    return x>=this.from && x<=this.to;
  }
}

r = new Range(1, 5);
console.log(r.toString());
console.log(r.includes(3), r.includes(7));
```

The constructor function is created and the prototype is assigned to that constructor. Then, when we call `new Range(1, 5)`, we create an empty object, we use the `Range` function to construct that object, and we link its prototype to the `Range.prototype`. This is all being done for us by the `new` keyword.

The `class` version is doing the exact same thing we've done here using a function/prototype, it's simply happening behind the scenes. So other than the fact I named mine `Range` and yours is `Range2`, they do exactly the same thing.

Javascript is quite different from most class-based languages, and there are gotchas. Prototypal inheritance is defining an *event delagate*, rather than a true "parent class".

Answer (score 2):

You asked:

> What is the prototype of this Range2 class?

That question appears to me to be the same as the question "What is the prototype of the entity bound to the variable `Range2`?" The answer to that question is:

```
Function.prototype
```

which is the prototype of any object that is a function, and classes are functions in JavaScript. Here's a Node console session that shows this:

```
$ node
> class C {}
undefined
> typeof C
'function'
> Object.getPrototypeOf(C) === Function.prototype
true
```

If your question is "What will be the prototype assigned to all instances of objects I create of the class `Range2` then the answer would be:

```
Range2.prototype
```

since, as others have mentioned, `Range2` is just a function. And user Snowmonkey has shown the contents of this object.

Your question mentioned something about a constructor and you are looking for something similar to Python's `__init__`. Interestingly, JavaScript's notion of a constructor for a class turns out to be the function itself! And a reference to this function is stored in the `prototype` property of the function. Back in our console:

```
> C.prototype.constructor === C
true
```

It seems crazy perhaps, but it is quite powerful and useful. It allows dynamic lookup, for any object, of the function that created it. And since classes are factories for instances, it totally makes sense. Back in the console:

```
> const c = new C()
> c.constructor
[class C]
> c.constructor === C
true
```

In a way, an object's `.constructor` property is a lot like Python's `type` function. JavaScript's `typeof` operator can only return a string representation of a handful of dynamic types, including `"object"` - so the `constructor` property turns out to be useful, if you find yourself querying types at run time (which is probably a dubious thing to do often).